# How to translate MySQL to criteria queries?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, criteria, criteria-api

I want to translate MySQL query into criteria query equivalent.

I have tried this, its not working.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Data> cq = cb.createQuery(Data.class);
        Root<Data> a = cq.from(Data.class);
        Join<Data, Item> b = a.join("Data", JoinType.LEFT); //left join
        b.on(
                cb.and(
                        cb.equal(a.get("id"), b.get("id")),
                        cb.isNull(a.get("id"))
                )
        );
        cq.select(b);
        List<Data> results = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Here is the MySQL code:

```
select * from data t left join item a
on t.id = a.id
where a.id is null;
```

Comment: In your sql you have the is null condition in the WHERE clause and in the other query in the ON condition, this is quite different. That aside, does the query really work when you require a.id to be null and at the same time equal to t.id? Null is never equal to null.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put your where clause inside your on() statement.

You should leave    `b.on(cb.equal(a.get("id"), b.get("id")));`

and then filter cq for `cb.isNull(a.get("id"))`